# How to add itemscope to <html> tag in Joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0, google-rich-snippets

I have a FAQ page set up with rich snippets.
Google Search does not recognize it. I still need to add **itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage"** to the html tag.

How could I modify the html tag for 1 specific page?
My html tag currently looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr">
...
</html>
```

How can I add the code and make it look like this? For only 1 page?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" dir="ltr" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage>
...
</html>
```

Many thanks for any tips on this.

PS: I have the HeadTag plugin installed from RicheyWeb. This makes it easy to add something to the head of my page. But I can't add to the html tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's feasible for your page, have you considered placing your structured data inside a JSON snippet on the page?

I've included a sample JSON script for an FAQ page below.

Here's how it looks on a page: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/zYYaRea

And this page validates on the [Google Structured Snippet Validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/),

screenshot below.

[image]]

FWIW, [here's an online generator for an FAQ Structured Data JSON snippet](https://saijogeorge.com/json-ld-schema-generator/faq/)

I hope this helps, good luck!

**Sample FAQ JSON snippet**

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "FAQPage",
      "mainEntity": [
        {
          "@type": "Question",
          "name": "Question 1",
          "acceptedAnswer": {
            "@type": "Answer",
            "text": "Answer 1"
          }
        },
        {
          "@type": "Question",
          "name": "Question 2",
          "acceptedAnswer": {
            "@type": "Answer",
            "text": "Answer 2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
</script>
```